# Why is caching not working while fetching Data on the Server with fetch?

Tags: next.js, http-caching

I have created a post listing application and upon clicking on each post the user will be redirected to single details page of the post

index.js (list of posts)

```
export default function Home(props) {
    const [postData, setPostData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", { next: { revalidate: 10 } })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setPostData(data);
            });
    }, []);

    const cardArr = postData.map((post) => <Card data={post} key={post.id} />);

    return (
        <Layout>
            <Header>
                <div>Posts</div>
            </Header>
            {cardArr}
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

[id].js (single post detail page)

```
export const PostPage = (props) => {
    const router = useRouter();

    const [post, setPost] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${router.query.id}`, {
            next: { revalidate: 1000 },
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setPost(data);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <Layout>
            <Header>
                <div className={styles.header}>{post.title}</div>
            </Header>
            <div>{post.body}</div>
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default PostPage;
```

I am trying to implement route caching. Such that if I go to one post then request is made to the server and the data will be cached. Next time if I go to same route within some time then instead of fetching data from the server it should display data from the cache.

I followed next js documentation where they used

```
{ next: { revalidate: 10 } }
```

But it is not working please guide me if I am missing something.

Comment: Might the "wrong" fetch. Did you import fetch?

Comment: @grekier There is not any need to import anything at all, `fetch` works out of the box.

Comment: @FabioNettis I know but a common mistake is to import it from another library and cache would not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you seem to mixing app-dir with pages-dir logic. In reality you are not fetching anything "on the server" but on the client, judging by the usage of `useEffect` and `useState` inside your components. As server components you would define it like this:

```js
export default async function Home(props) {
  // See how the function is asynchronous and I directly fetch inside 
  // the function body, without any effect whatsoever.
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
    next: { revalidate: 10 },
  });

  const postData = await response.json();

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Header>
        <div>Posts</div>
      </Header>
      {postData.map((post) => (
        <Card key={post.id} data={post} />
      ))}
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Furthermore I have noticed you seem to be using the router from `next/router`, that only works inside the `pages` directory. When using the app directory you would be importing it from `next/navigation`, and retrieve your query from the `searchParams` prop passed to every page.

---

I strongly recommend you take a look at the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs) for the new app-router since you do not seem to understand the fundamentals at all.